# WooCommerce update template log with explanation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wonder if there is a place on the world wide web, where I can find a WooCommerce update log with an explanation why a template is changed.

On GitHub, they have releases and tags with source files only without explanation. Of course *Google is your best friend* but I can't find it.

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt . it contains template changes as well

Comment: I've looked at your link, but it doesn't contains what I'm looking for. Here is an example on version 3.3.0 the template orderby.php is changed, but there is no explanation why it changed, is the new code better? Is the code update for something else, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the changelog is somewhat comprehensive, but you can also look into their official [Development Blog](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/).

You could clone WooCommerce after a release with GitHub and see changes in the tool there which will show line-by-line differences. GitHub Desktop is available for Windows, MacOS, and Linux.

Otherwise, you can use an online tool like [Diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) to put your old template on the left and the new template on the right to find any differences and see whether it is something you need to worry about and apply.